# Increase Paho-MQTT publishers running on Azure Container Instances (Locust Load Test)

Tags: python, azure, mqtt, paho, locust

We are trying to run a distributed Locust MQTT tests using Azure Container Instances and the Python Paho-MQTT library. We can't run more than 340 clients per worker.

```bash
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files.
```

The problem is related with the following issues:

- https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/issues/183
- https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/issues/662

With Docker the soft and hard limits can be changed using --ulimit, but ACI does not accept Docker arguments.

We changed the ACI entry point to increase the open files soft limit running the following bash script:

```bash
ulimit -Sn 10000

locust
```

We added to the locustfile.py:

```py
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE, (200000, 200000))
```

We also tried to use the following command:

```bash
sudo sysctl -w fs.file-max=500000

sysctl -p
```

But it returns a permission denied error.

Any idea?

Comment: Assuming the container is a running on a shared host I suspect that you won't be able to change the limit because it would impact other users containers

Comment: Maybe rephrase your title if you want more attention to your core issue (not being able to increase limits).

Comment: We regularly run docker instances with tens of thousands of open MQTT connections with no problem for a total of 100,000 sockets per VM. Don't know about ACI.

Comment: Thanks for your comments on my first question. Using VM is another solution, but it's not as easy as deploying a container from our CI.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an ACI problem but how the Paho-MQTT client is built. Paho uses the `select(..)` method which limits us to opening more than 1024 file descriptors.

Each MQTT client means 3 open file descriptors: 3 * 340 = 1020. Over 340 client connections, we hit the 1024 open file descriptors.

We use an MQTT User which inherits from the Paho Client. We overrode the following `_loop(..)` method to use Python selectors instead of select.

```py
import selectors
from paho.mqtt.client import Client

class MQTTClient(Client): 
[...]
    def _loop(self, timeout: float = 1.0) -> int:
       if timeout < 0.0:
            raise ValueError("Invalid timeout.")

        sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()

        eventmask = selectors.EVENT_READ

        with suppress(IndexError):
            packet = self._out_packet.popleft()
            self._out_packet.appendleft(packet)
            eventmask = selectors.EVENT_WRITE | eventmask

        if self._sockpairR is None:
            sel.register(self._sock, eventmask)
        else:
            sel.register(self._sock, eventmask)
            sel.register(self._sockpairR, selectors.EVENT_READ)

        pending_bytes = 0
        if hasattr(self._sock, "pending"):
            pending_bytes = self._sock.pending()

        if pending_bytes > 0:
            timeout = 0.0

        try:
            events = sel.select(timeout)
        except TypeError:
            return int(MQTT_ERR_CONN_LOST)
        except ValueError:
            return int(MQTT_ERR_CONN_LOST)
        except Exception:
            return int(MQTT_ERR_UNKNOWN)

        socklist: list[list] = [[], []]

        for key, _event in events:
            if key.events & selectors.EVENT_READ:
                socklist[0].append(key.fileobj)

            if key.events & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
                socklist[1].append(key.fileobj)

        if self._sock in socklist[0] or pending_bytes > 0:
            rc = self.loop_read()
            if rc or self._sock is None:
                return int(rc)

        if self._sockpairR and self._sockpairR in socklist[0]:
            socklist[1].insert(0, self._sock)
            with suppress(BlockingIOError):
                self._sockpairR.recv(10000)

        if self._sock in socklist[1]:
            rc = self.loop_write()
            if rc or self._sock is None:
                return int(rc)

        sel.close()

        return int(self.loop_misc())
```

**UPDATE:**

The register step must be wrapped by the `try-catch` block to avoid errors when reconnecting.

```py
        try:
            if self._sockpairR is None:
                sel.register(self._sock, eventmask)
            else:
                sel.register(self._sock, eventmask)
                sel.register(self._sockpairR, selectors.EVENT_READ)

            events = sel.select(timeout)

        except TypeError:
            # Socket isn't correct type, in likelihood connection is lost
            return int(MQTT_ERR_CONN_LOST)
        except ValueError:
            # Can occur if we just reconnected but rlist/wlist contain a -1 for
            # some reason.
            return int(MQTT_ERR_CONN_LOST)
        except Exception:
            # Note that KeyboardInterrupt, etc. can still terminate since they
            # are not derived from Exception
            return int(MQTT_ERR_UNKNOWN)
```